# Use the QGIS print layout to crop the layers it exports?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-export

I am currently processing data in QGIS, which I then want to export to Adobe Illustrator for further styling. Ideally I want to export the data as an SVG.

When I export the data using the QGIS print layout, I find that it exports the entire layer, not just the area that is within the extent of my map. Ideally I want to to remove all points outside the extent of my map, as well as crop any polygons overlapping the edge of my map so that only the relevant data is included.

I'm aware that a viable workaround would be to create a polygon representing the extent of my map, then clip the data layers to that polygon, but is there a way to do it directly from the print layout export menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you export to SVG from the print layout a pop up says this

"The SVG export function in QGIS has several problems due to bugs and deficiencies in the underlying Qt SVG library. **In particular, there are problems with layers not being clipped to the map bounding box.**"

So I don't think it's possible directly from the print layout, only the workaround that you suggested.

Comment: I was hoping had made a plugin or something to obviate the issue, but it looks like you're right. Thanks!